# min-height is not overriding

Tags: css

I've the following css:

```
textarea{
    height: 200px;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

And I want to override for some textarea:

```
<textarea style="height:auto;min-height:auto;"></textarea>
```

And as far as I know inline-style takes priority but why it's taking from external css?

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uYyd/)

Comment: :It is taking `height:auto` from inlne css.But for some reason it is not taking min-height from inline

Comment: Inline styles have the highest priority of all CSS.

Comment: min-height only has inherit value, you can use that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`min-height` doesn't have `auto` value so you are feeling it's not overriding. Just change it to `0` and see if it works.

```
<textarea style="height:auto;min-height:0;"></textarea>
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uYyd/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was having a headache on this.

Comment: I think min-height does have an auto value - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height

Answer (score 0):

Use inherit

```
<textarea style="height:auto;min-height:inherit"></textarea>
```

Comment: nb. `!important` is generally seen as bad practice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#The_!important_exception

Answer (score 0):

- We can use `min-height:0px`  to override.